# unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'str' and 'int' strange behaviour of Python (Remote)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, typeerror, remote-access, remote-debugging

I saw many posts with this error but mine seems to be really strange. I have remote interpreter so, I works on windows with Pycharm and it's connected with my Raspberry pi3. Strange thing is that If I run code via pycharm it works like charm but if I go to raspberry console and here try to lunch script as a `sudo python mycode.py` it gives me this error

> ```
>   unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'str' and 'int'
> ```

So I have same code lunching in 2 ways and I get different result. What can cause it and how to fight it ?

code where it gives error :

```
v = ((bytes_arr[k] << 24) & 0xFF000000) | ((bytes_arr[k+1] << 16) & 0xFF0000) | \
            ((bytes_arr[k+2] << 8) & 0xFF00) | (bytes_arr[k+3] & 0xFF)
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the line with the error? There's no `-` operator there.

Comment: full error looks like : `((bytes_arr[k+2] << 8) & 0xFF00) | (bytes_arr[k+3] & 0xFF)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'str' and 'int'`

Comment: That means that `bytes_arr[k+2]` is a string, not a number. You need to find the code that fills in `bytes_arr` to see why that happened.

Comment: @Barmar like I said in question there is no problem when I run it via pycharm I was thinking that maybe using console script to run I doesn't get imports or python version mess up something If there will be this string problem it will doesn't work by using pychar either

Comment: Just to make sure: You're running python 2.X on your windows machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RPi sometimes use different python version than we think try to run it as `sudo python3 mycode.py`